# Modify how datetime is presented in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm querying an SQL CE database to bind up a datasource for a datagrid to display some information.

One of the columns in the SQL CE database is a DateTime column. In the datagrid it displays the full date and time, what I'd like it to do is display the date in this format: mm/dd/yyyy

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: are you using linq to sql to query you can also before you bind read all results to a list and then modify how date is stored

Comment: No I'm just using an SQL expression...

Comment: id would be nice to see your grid but you can format a row in a grid on asp like somethink like that DataFormatString="{0:d}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know which column has date you could modify property of cell style for column:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle dgvCellStyle1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
dgvCellStyle1.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
dgvCellStyle1.NullValue = null;
this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle = dgvCellStyle1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can modify your query and use convert function to display date in desired format

```
convert(varchar(10), datetimefieldname, 103)
```

Another approach could be following, although I wouldn't prefer it much

```
cast(month(logindatetime) as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast(day(logindatetime) as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast(year(logindatetime) as varchar(4))
```